# Data sync with vb.net and php

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, data-synchronization

I have a windows application and a php web application(not connected to internet all times), eventually data add/remove/update can happen at either places. So data has to be synchronized every day or manually.

I have a small sqllite database file (less than 500K) in my end, and the php web app uses Mysql, the structures remain the same.

I would like to have a update function in my windows app, which sends my sqllite database file directly to my webserver and then
1. Php should read values from the sqllite database files insert some values into mysql from the uploaded file
2. Php should read values from the mysql database files and insert them to sqllite database file

and finally send them back to my windows client pc. I would like to use .net 2.0.

Anyone has an idea to get the above done or a suggestion to make the sync easier will help me a lot. 
Please Give me light on how the architecture or design should be done to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the database system is affordable I recommend you to take a look at [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/db4o/). It offers out of the box syncronization with their [replication system](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/drs/) counterpart. It's 100% managed and it also runs on Windows Mobile devices.

Furthermore its easier, cleaner and faster than whatever RDMS you could imagine and server-less if you need to (like sqlite).